Vuedraggable add handle help needed
I have a question regarding vue draggable. I am currently using Laravel and Vue.js and I want to create an effect where i am able to drag and drop using a handle. The issue i am dealing constantly is that whenever i add codes from some references it will say things like Error: draggable element must have an item slot. I did found a solution for it but the items are only for simple transitions, whenever i need to insert a transition element or a handle, It will say somethings like need an item slot. I need to know why this occurs and how should i resolve this. Currently does not concern about backend and only looking at frontend.
For now this is the code below demo App.vue:
Demo webpage
Desire Result of handle
reference page: https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/handle
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

const myArray = ref([
    { name: "McDonalds", id: 0 },
    { name: "KFC", id: 1 },
    { name: "Burger King", id: 2 },
    { name: "Mamak", id: 3 },
    { name: "4-Fingers", id: 4 },
    { name: "Sushi King", id: 5 },
]);

const oldIndex = ref('');
const newIndex = ref('');

const onEnd = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt);
    oldIndex.value = evt.oldIndex;
    newIndex.value = evt.newIndex;
};
</script>

<template>
    <div class="app">
        <h1 class="page-title">Favourite Foods</h1>


        <transition-group type="transition" name="flip-list">
            <draggable v-model="myArray" options="{animation:200, handle:'.my-handle'}" ghost-class="ghost" @end="onEnd">
            <!-- Define the `item` slot to render each draggable item -->
            <template v-slot:item="{ element }">
                <div class="sortable" :key="element.id">
                    <strong>{{ element.name }}</strong>
                    <span>{{ element.id }}</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrows my-handle"></i>
                </div>
            </template>
        </draggable>
        </transition-group>

        <p><strong>Previous Index: </strong>{{ oldIndex }}</p>
        <p><strong>New Index: </strong>{{ newIndex }}</p>
    </div>
</template>



<style scoped>
/* CSS Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Base font size */
html {
    font-size: 25px;
}

/* Specific styles for h1 */
.page-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Styles for draggable items */
.sortable {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #db9292;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: move;
    margin-bottom: 2px;

    span {
        float:right;
    }
}

/* Effects below for disabling ghost drag effect */
.app .sortable-drag {
    opacity: 0;
}

.flip-list-move {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.ghost {
    border-left: 6px solid rgb(0, 183, 255);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    opacity: 0.7;
}

</style>

This code above is the workable function workaround need an item slot. Although it works, i would like to insert a handle to only limit the dragable function as to not accidently drag the section.
How should i approach this?
Just for refference, this is the package.json that shows what version of vuedraggable i have install
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^5.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37",
        "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.4.21"
    }
}

